# android studio app not running error class not found exception on dexpathlist

Tags: android-studio

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hitapp, PID: 8211
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application YourPakageName.EnableMultiDex package com.example.hitapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "YourPakageName.EnableMultiDex" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~FOASvDKYQcT7MtbOyq7Nbw==/com.example.hitapp-gJW-z_0tG6FXAo3eqDw3DA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~FOASvDKYQcT7MtbOyq7Nbw==/com.example.hitapp-gJW-z_0tG6FXAo3eqDw3DA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "YourPakageName.EnableMultiDex" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~FOASvDKYQcT7MtbOyq7Nbw==/com.example.hitapp-gJW-z_0tG6FXAo3eqDw3DA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~FOASvDKYQcT7MtbOyq7Nbw==/com.example.hitapp-gJW-z_0tG6FXAo3eqDw3DA==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

how to solve my problem

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).